# Converting string with multiple dates into a dd-mm-YYYY format

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I have a DB table with relation 1: N where `N` represents multiple dates for one event. The column with the dates is `DateTime` type, and I would like to keep the `Time` option for later use, but it won't be so bad if I have to change it to `Date` type.

The problem comes when I have to show those multiple dates in some `GUI`. I get the dates with the `GROUP_CONCAT` function which means that in JavaScript I operate with a string with comma-separated values representing the different dates, which by now is in the default SQL `DateTime` format - `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

I use the `split(',')` function to get each date-time value and what I can do is to change the type of the SQL column to `Date` so when I split the string in JavaScript to end up with `YYYY-mm-dd` values. Which should be reversed to `dd-mm-YYYY` for the `GUI`.

I'm not sure how to proceed here. I have in mind two main options:

First: Maybe there's a way to use `dd-mm-YYYY` format in SQL which will solve all the problems.

Second: some kind of (complex?!?) String manipulation in JavaScript to split the string of dates into an array with multiple elements and then try to format each element the way I need.

Honestly - I want to avoid the second option, but don't know if the first is possible, and maybe, there's another way that I haven't think of.

Comment: Just to make it clear for those that my try this with CodeIgniter and AR. To make this work you need to make second select just for this. Here is what I mean : `$this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( mails_dates.dt_sending_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS sending_dates", FALSE );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( date_time_column, '%d-%m-%Y' )) FROM test_table;
```

Comment: Looks like should do the trick but I get this error: `Error Number: 1054, Unknown column '%d-%m-%Y' in 'field list'`. Maybe it's in my syntax, I use CodeIgniter AR and the selections looks like this:`GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( mails_dates.dt_sending_date, %d-%m-%Y )) AS sending_dates`

Comment: you are using Mysql or something else? The syntax I have written is checked on mysql.. you can format it acc to you if you are using something else any api or tool.

Comment: phpmyadmin and CodeIgniter AR

Comment: No idea about CodeIgniter AR. You can run the query at phpmyadmin, if you are not getting desired result, please let me know.

Comment: yes I do, gonna accept your answer, I'm just waiting to see if anyone with CodeIgniter experience won't writer something, because obv. the problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I advise to use the native Date/DateTime-format everywhere in your code and only use localized variations like dd-mm-yyyy only where you really want to display it. First reason: it is consistent in your code. Second reason: Sorting.

Example:

```
2012-03-01    >    01-03-2012
2012-05-12    >    12-05-2012
2012-01-03    >    03-01-2012
```

Sorted by the native format you'll get...

```
1: 2012-01-03
2: 2012-03-01
3: 2012-05-12
```

Sorted by the output format dd-mm-yyyy it will look like this...

```
1: 01-03-2012
2: 03-01-2012
3: 12-05-2012
```

...and I doubt this is what most people want.

**Adjusting the output via SQL**

You can change the output in your SELECT-query , most RDBMS offer functions for this. For example, in MySQL it is [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), which looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

**Adjusting the output via SQL**

You can also change the output using php, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358143/change-the-format-of-a-date-in-php).

**Adjusting the output via JavaScript**

It isn't hard to do this in JavaScript, too: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) is a great SO post which explains it in detail.

Comment: Thanks gonna look though all your links, but I think for this case it wont be problem to use `DATE_FORMAT`, could you see my comment on the first answer and point where could the problem be in my `SELECT` statement for getting this error?

Comment: Escape the date format in `DATE_FORMAT` properly. Instead of `DATE_FORMAT( mails_dates.dt_sending_date, %d-%m-%Y )` use `DATE_FORMAT( mails_dates.dt_sending_date, '%d-%m-%Y' )`!

Comment: sadly, but that was my first thought too - don't work. Anyways, thanks a lot, there is a lot of useful info in your answer. Big thanks.